# Return innerHTML inclusive of the tag you're targeting?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to return the `innerHTML` of a tag, inclusive of the tag I'm targeting. Let's say you have this HTML:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <p>Text 3</p>
</div>
```

And this JS:

```
const divInner = document.querySelector('.parent').innerHTML
console.log(divInner)
```

The console log will return only the html inside of the div tags:

```html
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <p>Text 3</p>
```

Is there a way to return the `innerHTML` INCLUSIVE of the parent tag (the div), so that the `console.log` returns this entire section, without creating another parent container outside of the div?:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <p>Text 3</p>
</div>
```

I know I can do this if I just add another parent div outside the inner div and target the parent div's `innerHTML` instead, but I'm trying to apply this on a page where adding more divs will screw up the alignment / spacing and I don't wish to readjust it all over again if I can avoid it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: you could also just do `document.querySelector('.parent').parentElement.innerHTML`  ;) but yeah `outerHMTL` is way to go.

Comment: Thanks guys! The outerHTML worked for me. I didn't know it existed.

Comment: And thanks @ikiK! I thought of that, but in my case in real life, the parent element contains many div tags that I don't want to return the HTML for, because I'm trying to target only the div tags that contain a certain word in their innerHTML. So I have looped through all the divs, created an array with only the div's that meet a certain requirement, and I want to display the innerHTML of only those div's, inclusive of their parent div tag, if that makes sense!

Comment: @KatieReynolds If I understand you correctly, I think `outerHMTL` will return all elements inside + parent. Not sure is this what you need in real life. Its the same as my suggestion. If you want to te return html without some specific divs inside outerHTML you will have to do filtering the other way.

Comment: @ikiK it works in my situation—I tried. I have something like, ```<div><div>Empty 1</div><div>Empty 2</div><div class="wrapper">Stuff</div></div>```, and when I target .wrapper.outerHTML I correctly get just ```<div class="wrapper">Stuff</div>```, without the parent ```<div>``` around it!

Comment: @KatieReynolds Sorry I can not re-create that :( But hey as long as it works for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using `outerHTML`.

> The `outerHTML` attribute of the element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

```js
const divInner = document.querySelector('.parent').outerHTML;
console.log(divInner);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <p>Text 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't heard of outerHTML before. This worked for me. I will mark yours as the answer!

Comment: @KatieReynolds, glad to help.